# I would like to get the Jenkins jobs status from a Angular JS page. Can you suggest any solutions to this

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, status

My requirement is to get the Jenkins job status (`Success` or `Failure`) from my AngularJS page.

My AngularJS page is triggering a Jenkins Job remotely using the URL. I would like to get the status and display on the AngularJS page once the jenkins job has done

Any suggestion in this regard would be much appreciated

Comment: Have you looked at [node-jenkins-api ](https://github.com/jansepar/node-jenkins-api) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could maybe use the API (add `/lastBuild/api/json` to the URL you used to kick off the job) and check for the `result` in the json. if it's null, it's still running. if it's not null, it will hopefully say "SUCCESS". at the bottom of each jenkins page there is a link to the API that you can use to find more details.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Comment: it will be better if there is little more explanation